# Unable to use json response properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Im using [datatables](https://datatables.net/usage/i18n) to show data and I want to fetch language settings from my server in a nice way. The problem is to format the data in a way that makes this possible, I would prefer to use json format with as few modifications as possible.

I want to use this:

(as an argument for my datatable creation, what is this? array? object? json string?)

```
var oLanguage =    
{ 
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ per page"
    }
};
```

I try to obtain this data from the server using this method:

```
$.getJSON( '/olan', function(data){
    oLanguage=data;
});
```

SERVER CODE: (PHP, [SLIM](http://www.slimframework.com/))

```
$app->get('/olan', function() use ($app, $lan){
    $oLanguage = array('oLanguage' => array('sLengthMenu' => '_MENU_ per page'));
    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $response->body(json_encode($oLanguage));
});
```

I was able to iterate through the data in the $.getJSON method and all information is there, must be something with the format/object handling. I don't yet have a good understanding of the type of object that i need, i can declare it, but i don't know what it is:) I hope its some kind of json object so i can just easily get it as i try to do. I could maybe declare it using $.each iteration but it would be ugly.

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, thank you for helping me out

-------------------------Answer (cannot post it the first 8 hours)---------------

Turns out,

> thanks to [Shinosha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091281/shinosha)

, that there is a build in feature of datatables to get the language settings from server. By creating the table like this:

```
$('#tableid').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/olan"
        }
});
```

and editing my server code: (changing the $oLanguage variable)

```
$app->get('/olan', function() use ($app, $lan){
    $oLanguage = array('sLengthMenu' => '_MENU_ per page');
    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $response->body(json_encode($oLanguage));
});
```

It works!

> *In Javascript, [] denotes array and {} denotes object. You can nest objects and arrays as required. Use a json validator like jsonlint.com
>   to validate your server response.* , [gvmani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825844/gvmani)

oLanguage is an object with the attribute oLanguage which is an object with the attribute sLengthMenu. sLengthMenu have the value "*MENU* per page"

```
var oLanguage =    
{ 
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ per page"
    }
};
```

Comment: See http://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n#how_to and http://datatables.net/usage/i18n

Comment: Thanks Shinosha, 

setting "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "/olan"
}

and editing server variable $oLanguage = array('sLengthMenu' => '_MENU_ per page') works!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, [] denotes array and {}  denotes object. You can nest objects and arrays as required. Use a json validator like jsonlint.com to validate your server response.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i now have a better understanding of Javascript:)